# Navigating to a specific directory

Tags: macos

I recently moved to a Macbook Air but I am having trouble navigating the file structure.  In windows, I have the windows explorer to navigate all of my local folders.  It appears the 'finder' application is the Mac's windows explorer equivalent.  The finder is just fine if I want to go to a folder in the left 'favorites' list, or even a few folders under the one i'm in, but for anything else it gets a little too complicated.

I need to save a file to /Users/MyUser/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages but when I download it from the internet, there is no easy way to save a file to this folder!  If I type this path into the search bar, it will return all files containing 'Users', 'MyUser', 'Library', etc...

In windows, I could paste this path and it would simply take me to the Packages folder.  How do I accomplish the same thing on the Mac???

Comment: you could do it in a terminal? cp Downloaded_file target_path

Comment: Oh man, that's overly complicated. There isn't an easier way to just save a file from a webpage right from the browser?

Comment: if you click "File" in the browser, then you see "save As". Click that and a window should pop up. To specify directory/folder other than the default, click the down arrow and it'll expand. From there, can you navigate from your home directory? I know you said going from "Favourites" is complicated, but from your home perhaps?

Comment: That's it! Exactly what I was trying to find!!!  Please post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> in the Finder window and you can type or paste a full path (also available under the "Go" menu as "Go to Folder").